# Oracle CLOB can't insert beyond 4000 characters?

Tags: oracle, insert, clob

How do I insert more than 4000 characters to a CLOB type column?

```
--create test table s
create table s
(
      a clob
);
insert into s values('>4000 char')
```

Results in an error:

> ORA-01704:the string too long.

I want to insert a string of >4000 characters one time. How do I do it? Is it possible?

When I read the Oracle reference, `CLOB` can save max 4GB(Gigabyte)?

Comment: did you find the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum for one time insertion is 4000 characters (the maximum string literal in Oracle). However you can use the lob function `dbms_lob.append()` to append chunks of (maximum) 4000 characters to the clob:

```
CREATE TABLE don (x clob);


DECLARE 
 l_clob clob;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO don (x) VALUES (empty_clob()) --Insert an "empty clob" (not insert null)
    RETURNING x INTO l_clob;

    -- Now we can append content to clob (create a 400,000 bytes clob)
    FOR i IN 1..100
    LOOP
      dbms_lob.append(l_clob, rpad ('*',4000,'*'));
      --dbms_lob.append(l_clob, 'string chunk to be inserted (maximum 4000 characters at a time)');
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your example , But How can I insert a xml which is like this ,  jere I have pasted just a portion, original one is > 4000 bytes
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer''s Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
How to make different chunks .I am having very little knowledge about xml in oracle.Please help.

Answer (score 21):

- split the long character string into 4000 character or less chunks
- create clobs for each chunk using to_clob() function
- concatenate the clobs

Here is an example:

```
insert into <table> (clob_column)
  values
  (
      to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
    ||to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
    ||to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
    ...
    ||to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
  );
```

Comment: This four-year-old question already has an accepted (and also four-year-old) answer. Also for future reference, consider adding more than just code, like an explanation of how your code works.

Comment: You're wrong and @TheJim01 is correct (and not trolling). All answers require explanation, and I'd say that any answer's explanation is *more* important than the code.

Comment: Yes the question got an accepted answer years ago. However, @gunn provides another approach which is easier imho. I also needed what OP asked for and preferred this one. I see commentators' points but couldn't leave this answer as-is, so edited the answer.

Comment: Although the approved comment was applicable, this worked perfectly for me in any case and you saved me some trouble :)

Comment: Oracle is the worst database I've ever worked on, often it has the ability to make complex a very simple task!

Answer (score -3):

Use a `clob` column and use `sqlldr` to import the data from a csv.

`sqldeveloper` can generate the necessary `control` `.ctl` script for you.