# I want to store more than 4000 character in oracle 11g

Tags: error-handling, oracle11g, sqldatatypes

I am working with Informatica mapping which updates a column in oracle table.
The column has a datatype of VARCHAR2 (4000).

Now I want to update the column with a value more than 4000 characters,i tried the datatypes LONG/CLOB but then also it is being able to accommodate only up to 4000 characters.

I also tried to to update the column using manual sql query but it is giving error.

Please advise the best way to store more than 4000 characters in the column.
Thanks in advance.

Rahul

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394691/oralce-clob-cant-insert-beyond-4000-character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oralce CLOB can't insert beyond 4000 character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394691/oralce-clob-cant-insert-beyond-4000-character)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column to LONG or LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB, BLOB), then you can do:

```
declare v LONG;
begin
v := 'stringwithmorethan4000characters...';
update YOUR_TABLE set  COLUMN_X = v where id=10;--use your own command
end;
```

Comment: OP wrote *i tried the datatypes LONG/CLOB but then also it is being able to accommodate only up to 4000 characters*